# API Documentation tool for Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, swagger, rails-api, api-doc

I have an API only rails app which needs documentation for frontend developers. And it's my first experience with it.

What tool do you use for this purpose? Note that I am using rails 5 API and not Grape.

I tested `Apipie`, `swagger-blocks`, and `swagger-docs` **gems**, but they are obsolete or buggy. There must be a better option!
Any recommendations respected

Answer (score 5):

Well, I found [Slate](https://github.com/lord/slate) one of the best out there.

Answer (score 2):

did you try RSpec Api Documentation? https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation

There is an article on using it with codeship here: https://blog.codeship.com/producing-documentation-for-your-rails-api/

Comment: Thanks for your response.   
I never used rspec before but wrote tests with simple rails test unit.   
Do you still prefer it to me? Can i run it fast?